# Correct notation for Cartesian product

Tags: soft-question, notation

I have already seen two notations for the Cartesian product of a family $\{A_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$:

$$\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_{\lambda}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathop{\LARGE\times}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_{\lambda}$$

Are these notations equivalent? If not, what's the difference between them and what of them is "more correct"?

Comment: The former is very common. I don't know any author who uses the latter notation.

Comment: Another I have seen is $A^\Lambda$.

Comment: @Alex S. I think that is the space of all mappings $[\Lambda \to A]$.

Comment: @Henry: The Cartesian product *is* the set of functions from $\Lambda$ to $A$ (provided, of course, that the sets $A_\lambda$ are the same).

Comment: @AlexS I didn't know that, which, in my opinion, is more "compact". Also, the "times" symbol in the question should be a bigger one, but I couldn't find a way to produce it (\bigtimes don't work).

Comment: @Brian M. Scott In this case each $A_\lambda$ is different.

Comment: @Larara There is a post on Tex. SE about how to produce a big $\times$.

Comment: @Henry You're right. Each $A_\lambda$ may be a different space; $A^\Lambda$ works if they are all the same.

Comment: @HenryW. maybe $A_{\lambda}^{\Lambda}$ (where the subscript is assumed to vary)?

Comment: @Larara: Your first notation is absolutely standard. Your second (with the large cross) is rare, though I have seen it a few times. If all of the sets $A_\lambda$ are the same set $A$, you can of course write $A^{|\Lambda|}$ or, if you with to emphasize the fact that the elements of the power are functions from $\Lambda$ to $A$, $A^{\Lambda}$ or ${^{\Lambda}A}$, of which I prefer the latter.

Comment: @Larara $A_\lambda^\Lambda$ is ambiguous. It could also be $[\Lambda \to A_\lambda]$.

Comment: @Larara: Unless there is an extremely good reason not to do so, you should use the standard notation. If you feel that you must shorten it, let $\mathscr{A}=\{A_\lambda:\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ and write $\prod\mathscr{A}$; this is also bog standard.